# keeping original message as well as extract Captured fields in regex

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I am parsing line using regex

String : `2013-3-03 14:27:33 [main] INFO  Main - Start`

Regex  : `/^(?<time>\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}) \[(?<thread>.*)\] (?<level>[^\s]+)(?<msg>.*)/`

This regex extracts below fields

```
"thread" :"main",
"level"  :"INFO",
"msg":"  Main - Start"
```

Output which i want is :

```
"Message" : "2013-3-03 14:27:33 [main] INFO  Main - Start"
"thread" :"main",
"level"  :"INFO",
"msg":"  Main - Start"
```

As i can parse string message once only, is there a way to achieve desired output which keep RAW message as well as extracts fileds also ?

Comment: Why don't you just keep the raw string in a variable? and what language you're using the regex in? In Javascript the raw string is always include in the result even if there is no match! Whatever please show us your code so that we can understand the problem better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the whole pattern in another group `(?<message>` if you want to name it.

You can write group *thread* using a negated character `\[(?<thread>[^\]\[]*)]` class preventing some backtracking instead of using `.*`

Also `[^\s]+` can be written as `\S+`

```
^(?<message>(?<time>\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}) \[(?<thread>[^\]\[]*)\] (?<level>\S+)(?<msg>.*))
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nj70JH/1)

Comment: can you point me to some blogs to quickly understand backtracing in regex? Thanks